# Add "Other" option in a HTML form

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an output similar to the given image. That is, multiple choice with an "editable other option". If a user choice doesn't match the first option, then the answer can be added by using "Other". Please guide me that how can I edit this code in HTML and CSS.

```html
<input type="radio">answer1
<input type="radio">Other<br>
```

[image: form with other option]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS version

```css
#other {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#otherRad:checked ~ #other {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="radContainer"><input type="radio" name="rad">answer1
  <input type="radio" name="rad" id="otherRad"> <input  id="other" type="text" placeholder="Other" />
</div>
```

JavaScript solution, which is likely needed if you want to empty the field if deselected

```js
document.getElementById("radContainer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const other = document.getElementById("other")
  other.disabled = tgt.type && tgt.type === "radio" && tgt.id != "otherRad";
  if (other.disabled) other.value=""; // or not as you wish
})
```

```html
<div id="radContainer"><input type="radio" name="rad">answer1
  <input type="radio" name="rad" id="otherRad"> <input disabled id="other" type="text" placeholder="Other" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I share with you something that might help you on this. Please try using this.

```js
$('#radio_other').click(function(){
  $('.text_box').show();
});

$('#radio_answer').click(function(){
  $('.text_box').hide();
  $('.text_box').val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_answer">answer1
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_other">Other <input type="text" name="other" hidden class="text_box"><br>
```

Comment: Well thought the quesioner is concern about HTML and CSS only and posted my suggestion

Comment: @mplungjan I want to do it in HTML